# Updating a property in Core Data in a View Controller IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an Iphone App and I want to change one of the values in Core Data. Normally I have only done the `didselect` row at index path method in a table view. Now I am coming from a table view and going into one of the cells and want to make a change for one of the properties in that cell in the viewController.

Doing this : `NSManagedObject *d = [self.model.frc_Work objectAtIndex:1];` will give me an error.

```
//The way I have done it before

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
          NSManagedObject *d = [self.model.frc_Work objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          [d setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"status"];
}


//How do I do it this way 
- (IBAction)btnDone:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObject *d = [self.model.frc_Work objectAtIndex:1];

    [d setValue:self.tvTheNote.text forKey:@"notes"];

    [self.model saveChanges];

    self.tvTheNote.text = @"";

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My Frc Code is :

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)frc_Work

{

// If the frc is already configured, simply return it

if (_frc_Work) return _frc_Work;



// Otherwise, create a new frc, and set it as the property (and return it below)

_frc_Work = [_cdStack frcWithEntityNamed:@"Work" withPredicateFormat:nil predicateObject:nil sortDescriptors:@"title,YES" andSectionNameKeyPath:nil];



return _frc_Work;

}
```

Comment: what is `model` in your code? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: model is just were I have all my functions. The frc code in the model is :  - (NSFetchedResultsController *)frc_Work

{

    // If the frc is already configured, simply return it

    if (_frc_Work) return _frc_Work;

    

    // Otherwise, create a new frc, and set it as the property (and return it below)

    _frc_Work = [_cdStack frcWithEntityNamed:@"Work" withPredicateFormat:nil predicateObject:nil sortDescriptors:@"title,YES" andSectionNameKeyPath:nil];

    

    return _frc_Work;

}

Answer (score 0):

Create an index path using...

```
NSIndexPath rowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1];
```

Then call:

```
NSManagedObject *d = [self.model.frc_Work objectAtIndexPath:rowIndexPath];
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it based on the cell in the table view the user clicked instead of just specifying 1?

Comment: You could use the buttons tag to store the index number.e.g. - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    CustomCell *result = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
        cell.button.tag = index;